# How to deal with different childNode count by IE8 vs all other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a number of divs that I want to manipulate with events, like add/remove classes, attributes etc. I have nested elements. At first I was using the `children` collection, but since that was poorly supported I turned to `childNodes`.

However, now that I test it, with an alert to check the number of `childNodes`, I get e.g. 39 in all other browsers, and 20 in IE8. This makes looping unreliable, which I need to check for classes. My Javascript:

```
function removeOnclick(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('selections');
    var parent_length = parent.childNodes.length;
    alert(parent_length);
    for (var i=0; i<39; i+=2){
    if (parent.childNodes[i].hasAttribute("onclick")) {
        parent.childNodes[i].removeAttribute("onclick");
        }
    }
}
```

With this HTML formatting, all browsers count them as 20 (I have not pasted all 20 nodes):

```
<div id="selections"><div id="selection1" class="size" onclick="count(this.id);" onmouseover="onovershowpop(this.id);" onmouseout="onouthidepop(this.id);"><div class="pop">sample</div></div></div>
```

But with this formatting, all others browsers count 39 childNodes, while IE8 still counts 20:

```
<div id="selections">  
    <div id="selection1" class="size" onclick="count(this.id);" onmouseover="onovershowpop(this.id);" onmouseout="onouthidepop(this.id);">
        <div class="pop">sample</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I have to go into one line (div tag) every time to make it bulletproof?

Comment: Can't you just use `parent_length` instead of literal `39`?

Comment: Could you post your html? Most modern browsers will count whitespace between certain tags as text nodes; I don't believe IE8 does. It would help to see it though.

Comment: indeed since i have already have in my code the parent_length i could..
but still..since i.e.8 doesn't count the empty nodes, in the once instance where browsers identify 39 nodes i have to increase i by 2 in each loop, while in I.E.8 i would have to increase it by 1..

Comment: `.children[]` has been supported since IE5.5... Why is it not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 and below do not count empty text nodes as children. The `.children[]` array has been supported in IE since 5.5 and possibly earlier, with the slight error that the array counts comment nodes in IE8 and below. So long as there are no comments in the element (which there shouldn't be, HTML comments are never needed) then you can use `.children[]` reliably.

Comment: so children[], will give back the same result of the existing elements in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, assuming there are no HTML comments.

Comment: as you correctly mentioned, i haven't any html comments, and i shouldn't..i just made a copy of my file replacing childnodes with children, and seems cleaner solution than having my entire nested divs into one line.. thank you very much..